# Unwanted change of ownership of /root to uid 1000 (in: parted magic live system installed on USB pendrive; this happens when adding own programs)

Tags: chown

As in the title:
When I add programs to Parted Magic
(as described here:   https://partedmagic.com/adding-programs/  ; I actually "make my own bundle" by using "mksquashfs"; I applied `chmod 777 * -R`  to my filesystem before using "mksquashfs"; I then copyied the resulting *.sqfm file to the indicated folder (on the USB pendrive, which stays bootable; not nessessary to write the whole iso-image again); at the time of booting Parted Magic from the USB pendrive, my files are automatically installed by Parted Magic)
and I try to start firefox (which is part of the standard package of Parted Magic) this is not possible.
(when using parted magic as is ("out-of-the-box"), firefox can be started without any problem.)

The reason for this gets obvious when I open a terminal and enter "firefox", which is answered by:

> "Running Firefox as root in a regular user's session is not supported. ($HOME is /root which is owned by uid 1000.)

Now, as Parted Magic is a Live System, it is normal that everything is run as root. 
So, obviously the problem is that the ownership of /root is changed to uid 1000 but in order to work, the owner of /root should be root.
(uid 1000 being the first "normal" user (apart from root) that linux creates;  this is explained here https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/what-is-the-user-1000-a-4175510196/    )

I am able to start firefox when I change  the ownership of /root from UID 1000 to root, which can be done  by entering

```
chown root:root /root &&
chmod 744 /root
```

(I didn't try if the second line `chmod 744 /root`  is necessary to make it work)

Now, my question is:  Why does adding own programs (or even minor changes, like a textfile that is placed on the desktop of "Parted Magic") cause that ownership of /root is changed to uid 1000 ?  What do I need to do to avoid this change of ownership when adding stuff to "Parted Magic" ?

I hope this is the appropriate forum for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution to the problem was just one step away, and I still didn't see it: I forgot to **change  ownership** of the files before I used "mksquashfs".

So I used

> sudo chown root:root * -R

to change ownership of all files (and all subdirectories) in the current directory to root
(be careful: by this command, you can potentially wreak your system, if you apply it when being in the wrong directory)

What obviously happens is: When "Parted Magic"-  during the booting process - installs the files contained in the *.sqfm file that I added, it will change the ownership of /root in the case that one of the files that get added to /root in the process, are not owned by root.

So, even though this may be obvious to most Linux-savvy people, maybe this can be helpful to some newbie (like me) who uses Parted Magic ...